# Как можно переписать программу без использования одной библиотеки?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Программа выписывает из одного файла в другой только слова начинающиеся на гласную букву, как можно переписать эту программу не используя библиотеки fstream, но используя cstdio? Это вообще возможно?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    fstream out("D:\\zhopa.txt");
    ifstream in("D:\\gavno.txt"); // открываем файл для чтения
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        for (string word; in >> word; )
        {
            if (word.find_first_of("AEIOUYaeiouy") == 0)
            {
                out<< "\n"<<word;
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();     // закрываем файл

    cout << "Programm end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Замените работу с файлами через `FILE*`, чтение слова - `fscanf(f,"%s",...)`? проверку первого символа - через `strchr`. А вообще дали бы метку "С", а не "С++". А еще - дали бы не столь вызывающие имена файлам, все же в основном тут люди приличные и даже интеллигентные...

Comment: ой, я уже и забыл про имена, извиняюсь

Comment: А вы не могли показать как цикл в итоге будет выглядеть, я смог написать код, но в чтобы он в цикле работал на все слова в тексте никак не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то надо и самому работать. "Я смог написать" - и где он?

```
int main()
{
    FILE * out = fopen("out","wt");
    FILE * in  = fopen("in","rt");
    if (in)
    {
        char word[512];
        while(fscanf(in,"%s",word) > 0)
            if (strchr("AEIOUYaeiouy",word[0]))
                fprintf(out,"%s\n",word);
        fclose(in);
    }
    fclose(out);
    puts("Programm end");
}
```